# What is the correct way to cancel an Event Registration that is marked Pending Pay Later?

Tags: civievent, contributions, payment, paylater

we have been registering participants online for our paid events and marking them by default to "Pending Pay Later" status.  However, when some of the participants cancels their registration and we go into their Contribution record to cancel those contribution, the Payment field will register a deficit amount equal to the event fee.  Since payment was still pending when the cancellation of registration was made, we were expecting the payment amount to still be at zero.

i attach a screenshot of the contribution record of such a cancelled contribution to illustrate:

[image]

The Payment details (at the bottom of the screenshot) had Amount as $0 since this was "Pending Payment Later".  But when we change the Contribution Status to "Cancelled" to indicate a cancellation of this registration, the Amount changed to "-$30" which was the fee for the event.    this then affects the accounting as CIVICRM will think we are $30 short due to this cancellation.

Is it the case that "Cancelled" shouldn't be used in this case?  We tried others and it seems "Failed" will cancel the event registration and not register any deficit in the payment.  However, I would like to get the view of the community on whether this is the right way to cancel a event registration that is marked "Pending Pay Later"?

Also, if the behaviour of recording a deficit in Payment is correct when the event registration is changed to "Cancelled", what situation should this be used for ?  Is it when a refund is due?

Thanks.

[civicrm 5.10.4 - WP 5.3.2]

Comment: Are you registering people in the CiviCRM backend or via a form on the front facing website?

Comment: The events are registered online by the participants.